# How to add eventlistener on keypress to chrome's address bar - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there an API for google chrome extension that lets me add an event listener on key press in address bar?

I tried searching on the web, couldn't find anything.

Comment: No, definitely not.  I don't want a website to know where I'm going when I leave.  Sounds like a MASSIVE security risk to me.

Comment: @Archer — The question says "chrome extension". It isn't talking about JavaScript embedded in a website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unlike Firefox, Chrome doesn't expose its UI to extensions.

The only remotely related options are:

- [omnibox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) to add a keyword search.

  > When the user enters your extension's keyword, the user starts interacting solely with your extension. **Each keystroke is sent to your extension**, and you can provide suggestions in response. The suggestions can be richly formatted in a variety of ways. When the user accepts a suggestion, your extension is notified and can take action.
- [commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) to register a hotkey for the extension that will work everywhere, including the omnibox but the extension won't be able to read anything from it.
- <s>webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate or webRequest.onBeforeRequest in case the prediction service is enabled</s> - [impossible since Chrome 71](https://crrev.com/c/1242296)